# Tool to mount cloud drive as local disk on Windows

Tags: windows, cloud-storage

I'm looking for an application to mount cloud drives as a local disk in Windows PC.

Preferably

- lightweight
- maps a network drive Microsoft Windows that connects to all major cloud storage providers such as Dropbox, Google Drive, Google Team Drives, Amazon Drive, Box, OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, Sharepoint, Openstack Swift, BackBlaze B2, Amazon S3 or your own SFTP, FTP or WebDAV server and SMB/Windows File Sharing.
- open-source or Premium
- Super-fast background uploads
- Access the cloud through Finder and Explorer

Comment: Windows Explorer natively allows mapping to SMB and WebDAV servers. If your "cloud" provider allow either one you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Rclone (https://rclone.org/) is free and open source.

I have been using it on Linux, but a Windows version is available too.

Answer (score 0):

https://mountainduck.io/ is a good software which I use. Although it is not freeware.

From the product description:
Mountain Duck lets you mount server and cloud storage as a disk in Finder on macOS and the File Explorer on Windows. Open remote files with any application and work like on a local volume.